# Qt Creator: can't remote debug and qmake not executable for Qt5 Android armv7

Tags: android, qt-creator, qt5, qmake, armv7

I installed Qt 5.3.1 for android (qt-opensource-linux-x64-android-5.3.1).
In creator, in Qt Versions, it auto-detects:

- Qt 5.3 for Android armv7
- Qt 5.3 GCC 64bit

For both, it says

> qmake does not exist or is not executable.

In my project, I can't run the remote debugging. Placing the mouse over the run or debug buttons shows:

> the executable is not built by the current build configuration

Anyway, I can successfully compile.

Are the two problems related?
What should I do to run and debug my program?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to add it manualy (path to qmake is `qt_install_path/5.3.1/gcc_64/bin/qmake`) and then change your building kit to the new one (project tab on the left). And BTW did you have qt installed earlier ex. from repositories ?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, that solved part of my problem (adding manually the qmake). To reply, yes I had other installs of QtCreator. Now, I have an Android for armeabi-v7a kit but I can't run cmake because I don't have any choice in the generator list...any idea? thanks again!